# How do you send an instance variable from a rails Controller to a BackBone Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

Supposed I have two different Objects I am trying to load in an eventual BackBone view.

**My Rails Controller**

```
def index
  @visuals = Visual.all
  @words   = Word.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: [@visuals, @words] }
  end
end
```

On place I can add it is here :

**My Rails View:**

```
#visuals

:javascript
  $(function() {
    window.router = new AiProject.Routers.VisualsRouter({test_visuals: #{ @visuals.to_json.html_safe } });
    // AiProject.words = new Words(#{@words.to_json});
    //  ^^ Would this be the best place to insantiate my controller code's instance variable?
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
```

But other people say to put it in your template. Which is strange because I think my BackBone's framework puts it in the router:

**Coffee BB Router**

```
show: (id) ->
  visual = @visuals.get(id)

  @view = new AiProject.Views.Visuals.ShowView(model: visual)
  $("#visuals").html(@view.render().el)
```

So if that was the case, maybe I should try and insantiate `@words` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit - this was not talking about bootstrapping.

You need to be calling the `index` action somewhere, probably directly via `jQuery.ajax` as it doesn't correspond directly to a single backbone model or collection.

In the success handler of your ajax call, you can assign the returned data to whatever you want to assign it to in backbone.

I would probably have models for single visuals and words, then collections of each as well (in raw javascript as i'm out of practice with coffeescript at the moment):

```
MyApp.Models.Visual = Backbone.Model.extend();
MyApp.Models.Word = Backbone.Model.extend();

MyApp.Collections.Visuals = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyApp.Models.Visual
});

MyApp.Collections.Words = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyApp.Models.Word
});

var visuals, words;

$.ajax({
  url: <path to index action>
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    visuals = new MyApp.Collections.Visuals(data[0]);
    words = new MyApp.Collections.Words(data[1]);
  }
});
```

at this point, you have your `visuals` and `words` collections, and can do whatever you need to do with them.

Comment: You're saying the Rails controller, sends to the view, then the Backbone Model picks up the view, sends it to the controller, view and templates?

Comment: Yes, the handoff from rails to javascript occurs in the rails template. I'm still working under the assumption you're wanting to bootstrap data, as opposed to the case where you're already within the backbone app and are just fetching new data from the server.

Comment: Ah that was going to be my second question. I'll try and be more specific. I'm using a view specifically to load all the questions `@questions`, and one to load all the answers `@answers`. This would be a `questions/#new` route. Therefore, I would like to have both JSON objects available for me to pull from and manipulate at ease. Not sure if that would be your "bootstrapping" reference or not.

Comment: By bootstrapping, I mean there is data that's required by your backbone app in its initial load, and you need to hand it off from Rails to javascript. Once the app is loaded, you're just doing normal json requests, and the data handoff is trivial.

Comment: Ah then I don't mean bootstrapping as I have booted up my app in a fn.ready() and instantiated my router. Though I wouldn't mind this information be available within that bootstrap. Sorry for sounding daft, I'm just unclear as to what would be the *best* way possible to do this. In the plugin:  https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails I am using, it doesn't seem like they use the view, but rather the model. And looking at the model, I don't understand how they even move the model data.

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case, it sounds you want to use backbone collections, and [set the model](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) and [url](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url). Then you can use [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) to pull them back from the server. Backbone will automatically instantiate models for each type.

Comment: I provided more info above! :D Sorry, I'm also syntactically dis-inclined. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: no prob. I edited my answer now that we're on the same page (I think, ha)